# Render a different controller with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Quick question - is it possible to render an action for a different controller whilst also sending params?

In my `BookingsController` I have a `show` action that also displays a form used to update the details of a `Guest` using the `update` action of the `GuestController`

I would like to be able to render the `BookingsController` `show` action if validation errors occur but because it's the show action an ID is also required (@booking.id) - how can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to redirect back to BookingsController's show action if validations fail when user tries to submit the guest form. So you want to come from Guest to BookController's show. Am I getting it right?

Comment: Nearly, but if I redirect I will lose the validation error messages so render rather than redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay since you just want to render the show actions' view from your GuestController, simply do,

`render :template => "bookings/show"`

This should work.

Remember, code in your `bookins#show` will not be executed! You need to provide whatever instance variables `bookings#show` provides in your `guests#update`.

Comment: thanks for this - I forget about providing the instance variables within the other controller - still have a small issue - the `show` action renders a partial to display the booking but I'm getting a missing template error when I render the view from the `GuestController`

Comment: Are you rendering this partial from the show.erb? If so when rendering it, use `bookings/_partial` instead of just `_partial`.